# Remove titles from name string if found

Tags: python

I have some inputs which are like so;

```
[
'Joe Blohs', 
"MR John Smith", 
"Mr. Joe Bloggs",
"Dr. catherine Parr",
"Mrs Jane Janes",
'MRS. Jane Smith',
'DR John Thomas',
'MR BILL GATES',
'Prof. Jeff Bezos',
"ms kate smith",
"Mr mrlinka mrlinkov"
]
```

I would like to clean each line so that the Prefix is remove if its there; so the output should be;

```
['Joe Blohs', 
"John Smith", 
"Joe Bloggs",
"catherine Parr",
"Jane Janes",
'Jane Smith',
'John Thomas',
'BILL GATES',
'Jeff Bezos',
"kate smith",
"mrlinka mrlinkov"
]
```

There might be a title (or not), it might be in capitals (or not) and it might have a full stop (or not), I would expect it to have a space and I think the only titles I am likely to find are;
Miss, Ms, Mrs, Mr, Dr, Prof the most commonly used professional ones.

I had tried this;

```
txt = "Dr Drake Bill Gates"

x = txt.lstrip("Ms ").lstrip("MS ").lstrip("Mrs ").lstrip("MRS ").lstrip("Mr ").lstrip("MR ").lstrip("DR ").lstrip("Dr ").lstrip(".")
print(x)
```

But it seems very clumsy and seems to ignore the space at the end of each lstrip() so it would remove the Dr from Drake if there wasn't a Dr in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach using re.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = [
'Joe Blohs', 
"MR John Smith", 
"Mr. Joe Bloggs",
"Dr. catherine Parr",
"Mrs Jane Janes",
'MRS. Jane Smith',
'DR John Thomas',
'MR BILL GATES',
'Prof. Jeff Bezos',
"ms kate smith",
"Mr mrlinka mrlinkov"
]

titles = ("MR","DR","MRS","PROF","MS")
ptrn = re.compile(fr"^({'|'.join(titles)})\.?\s+", flags=re.I)
data = [ptrn.sub("", i)  for i in data]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['Joe Blohs',
 'John Smith',
 'Joe Bloggs',
 'catherine Parr',
 'Jane Janes',
 'Jane Smith',
 'John Thomas',
 'BILL GATES',
 'Jeff Bezos',
 'kate smith',
 'mrlinka mrlinkov']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `.replace`.

```
text = [
'Joe Blohs', 
"MR John Smith", 
"Mr. Joe Bloggs",
"Dr. catherine Parr",
"Mrs Jane Janes",
'MRS. Jane Smith',
'DR John Thomas',
'MR BILL GATES',
'Prof. Jeff Bezos',
"ms kate smith",
"Mr mrlinka mrlinkov"
]

replaceitems = ['MR ', 'Mr. ', 'Dr. ', 'Mrs ', 'MRS. ', 'DR ', 'MR ', 'Prof. ', 'ms ', 'Mr ']

for i in range(len(text)):
    for item in replaceitems:
        text[i] = text[i].replace(item, '')
print(text)
```

You can add items to replaceitems list, then replace it by using `.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no middle names in your list, the below is a neat way because you do not need to specify 'Mr','Mrs','Dr',etc, therefore it is **robust** to typo's and other prefixes that you might have skipped above.

You can create a new list, say `new_li`, and `iterate` through all the elements in your current list and check whether each name consists of more than 2 words, if yes, remove the first part of it:

```
s = [
'Joe Blohs', 
"MR John Smith", 
"Mr. Joe Bloggs",
"Dr. catherine Parr",
"Mrs Jane Janes",
'MRS. Jane Smith',
'DR John Thomas',
'MR BILL GATES',
'Prof. Jeff Bezos',
"ms kate smith",
"Mr mrlinka mrlinkov"
]

new_list = []
for name in s:
    if len(name.split()) > 2:
        name_fixed = name.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        name_fixed = name_fixed.title()
        new_list.append(name_fixed)
    else:
        new_list.append(name.title())
```

which prints:

```
['Joe Blohs',
 'John Smith',
 'Joe Bloggs',
 'Catherine Parr',
 'Jane Janes',
 'Jane Smith',
 'John Thomas',
 'Bill Gates',
 'Jeff Bezos',
 'Kate Smith',
 'Mrlinka Mrlinkov']
```

Also converts to `title()` - first names and surnames will have their 1st letter capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
people = [
'Joe Blohs', 
"MR John Smith", 
"Mr. Joe Bloggs",
"Dr. catherine Parr",
"Mrs Jane Janes",
'MRS. Jane Smith',
'DR John Thomas',
'MR BILL GATES',
'Prof. Jeff Bezos',
"ms kate smith",
"Mr mrlinka mrlinkov"
]

prefix = ["Ms", "MS", "Mrs", "MRS", "Mr", "MR", "DR", "Dr", "Prof", "Ms.", "MS.", "Mrs.", "MRS.", "Mr.", "MR.", "DR.", "Dr.", "Prof.",]

for i in range(len(people)):
    person_split = people[i].split(" ")
    if person_split[0] in prefix:
        person_split.remove(person_split[0])
    people[i] = " ".join(person_split)
    
print(people)
```

This splits up the named based on a single space then looks to see if the first word in that name is within the prefixes. If so, it removes it.

Let me know if you have any questions.